# problem with .html()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i am using this [plugin](http://lagoscript.org/jquery/upload/demo?locale=en) but all works well less one thing.
In the example of developper in the final of upload is showed 3 info about the file
I want do something like that.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#userfile').change(function() {
                $(this).upload('thumb.php', function(res) {
                    $(res).insertAfter(this);
                }, 'html');
            });
        });

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
        <br />
```

At the moment only the image is uploaded and none message is showed.

The question is, in my php file i test a simple echo that is not showed in .html().

this is the example of the dev

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['yourkey']['tmp_name'], '/path/to/save/' . $filename)) {
    $data = array('filename' => $filename);
} else {
    $data = array('error' => 'Failed to save');
}

header('Content-type: text/html');
echo json_encode($data);
```

in my case i just test with a `echo "success";`

what i am doing wrong?

PS: awesome plugin

Comment: Try to `alert(res)` in `upload` event - what is the output ?

Comment: i already tested an alert() but nothing happens. simple upload the photo and stops the load of the page

Comment: no, the firebug console is clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is few reasons why your application does not work:

```
 $(this).upload('thumb.php', function(res) {$(res).insertAfter(this);}, 'html');
```

in this case upload sends to function a string element which you are trying to convert to DOMnode, so result of `res` suppose to be some html structure like

```
<li>some text</li>
```

your php code return JSON string which is treated as simple string by  uploader
if you are planning to use JSON formatted response change lasta parameter of `$(this).upload();` from `'html'` to `'json'`